CreateDialog and GraphicsArray
Bug introduced in 13.3 or earli and fixed in 14.1
I think I have hit on a true bug in the Mathematica Front End:
If I define
plotFunc[] := Print[GraphicsGrid[{{Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}], Plot[x^3, {x, 0, 1}]}}]];

I can execute the function:
plotFunc[]

and get as expected

If I now define
CreateDialog[{Button["Plot", plotFunc[]]}];

I get a little dialog

But if I press the button, the red 'Messages' window pops up with a the message:

The first line, with a red rectangle shows the error message "An invalid typeset structure was generated: Missing BoxData."
The problem only occurs, when two graphics are assembled, i.e. if there is a simple, single Plot[] call only in the plotFunc[], things work correctly.
Any ideas?

Are you sure that this is what CreateDialog is supposed to do? When I execute CreateDialog[{Button["Plot", p1 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]]}];, it brings up a dialog box.  When I hit the Plot button, nothing seems to happen. But when I execute p1 in the current notebook, it then displays the plot. I'm not sure that CreateDialog is mean to do things in the Front End. However, when I run your code, I don't get the error messages you are, but the plots are printed to the error message window that appears, which is weird.

Yes, the correct behaviour is that the plots appear in the error message window. This is where the output should go. - But the fact that it creates an error there is the issue.

Answer from technical support: "I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided."

I've added the bugs tag, since your message from technical support seems to indicate that it really is a bug.
